# Nested Routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models bodyparts and exercises.Both are having has_and_belongs_to_many relations

```
Bodyparts
has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises

Exercises
has_and_belongs_to_many :bodyparts
```

In my routes.rb file i have given,

```
resources :bodyparts do
    resources :exercises
end
```

I want to fetch all exercises belongs to a particular bodypart.

i have tested `http://localhost:3000/bodyparts/1/exercises.json`

but i am getting array of exercises.

How to solve this.

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that in your controller

```
def index
  @exercises = BodypartExercise.where( :muscle_id => params['muscle_id'])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @exercises }
  end
end
```

Comment: both models are having 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relations.I have also created a mapping table 'bodyparts_exercises' to map bodyparts_id and exercises_id. The answer you provided is best for has_many relation.It is not working in HABTM relation.

Comment: then you need BodypartsExercise.where( :muscle_id => params['muscle_id'])

Comment: bodyparts_exercises is just a table created through migration,it is not a model.